# Deserialize enums using the EnumMember value in AspNet [FromQuery] model binding

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, system.text.json, jsonserializer, custom-model-binder

I have an endpoint in .NET 6 `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` project that deserialize query strings into a .NET object by using the standard [FromQuery]

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SamplesController
    : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]QueryModel queryModel)
    {
        if (!queryModel.Status.HasValue)
        {
            return BadRequest("Problem in deserialization");
        }
        
        return Ok(queryModel.Status.Value.GetEnumDisplayName());
    }
}
```

The model contains an enum

```
public class QueryModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The foo parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>bar</example>
    public string? Foo { get; init; } = null;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The status
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>on-hold</example>
    public Status? Status { get; set; } = null;
}
```

And the enum has `EnumMember` attributes which value I want to use to deserialize from.

```
public enum Status
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "open")]
    Open,
    
    [EnumMember(Value = "on-hold")]
    OnHold
}
```

By default, .NET 6 does not take into consideration the `EnumMember` when deserializing.

The goal is to be able to send requests such as

```
http://localhost:5000/Samples?Foo=bar&Status=on-hold
```

and have the controller's action deserialize the `QueryModel` with the proper `Status.OnHold` value by using its `EnumMember`

I have tried without luck an extensions library that contains a converter, but the converter is not getting triggered when using `[FromQuery]`. See https://github.com/Macross-Software/core/issues/30

I have added a project to reproduce problem and as a sandbox to provide a solution**
https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/issues/string-to-enum-mvc/-/tree/feature/1-original-problem

NOTE: I would need a solution where the Enum and the does not require any external dependency (just .NET sdk).

Comment: `How do I customize de [FromQuery] model binder (assuming that's the best solution)?`If you only want to use it for parameters of actions,maybe you can [apply the model binder to parameters directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: @YiyiYou yes, but the `FromQuery` model binder gets the payload from the `bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query`. I could follow that approach if I knew how exactly AspNet Mvc deserializes the `IQueryCollection` to rely on the default mechanism except for the enums

Comment: I've just found this similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660327/webapi-model-binding-string-to-enum

Comment: As an aside, `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` from https://github.com/Macross-Software is a JSON converter.  It is used to bind enums to [application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819) body content in the [JSON format](https://json.org/).  Query parameters aren't in JSON format, so a System.Text.Json or Json.NET for that matter do not apply.

Comment: there is an ugly way, you can access the request by using `middleware` before serialization and then you should replace "-" with "" empty value (`the problem is how you know that key is enum`) helps to serialize but there is another case which is string query key can contain "anything" may cause another issue. but you can filter by `httpContext.Request.RouteValues` which contains `controller,action` names to get type of parameters to modify. **There is strict rule enum can not contain dashes "-" we can understand.** Or if it is unique case just filter by fullpath in `middleware`

Comment: Or simply use underscore `_`

Comment: @MustafaSalihASLIM using underscore in enum member does not make any difference when deserializing with default `[FromQuery]` mechanism or when plugging `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` which, as @dbc, doesn't work for query params

Comment: @diegosasw , I mean there is no way to use dashes with Enum/EnumMember (Including serialization, you may need JsonConverter for response but not request), you should use `on_hold` as an enum variable, then you may use DescriptionAttribute to get string value for the request?, this is easiest way. 
checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422407/finding-an-enum-value-by-its-description-attribute

Comment: I refactored the code used by `JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter`  from [System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061296/3744182) (demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pa6pD)) and used it to make an `EnumMemberModelBinderProvider` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rpXo77.  Can you check to see if this does what you want?  Composite numeric values for flag enums (e.g. "2,8") aren't working yet.  (Honestly the enum API is a pain.  There isn't even a `ToString()` method that returns a local-invariant result!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom Enum converter might be your choice. By leveraging the existing `EnumConverter` class what we need is to have a customized `ConvertFrom` method:

```
public class CustomEnumConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public CustomEnumConverter([DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicParameterlessConstructor | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicFields)] Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override object? ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string strValue)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(EnumType))
                {
                    var field = EnumType.GetField(name);
                    if (field != null)
                    {
                        var enumMember = (EnumMemberAttribute)(field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true).Single());
                        if (strValue.Equals(enumMember.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return Enum.Parse(EnumType, name, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new FormatException((string)value, e);
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

And then decorate the converter to your Model class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomEnumConverter))]
public enum Status
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "open")]
    Open,
    
    [EnumMember(Value = "on-hold")]
    OnHold
}
```

then we can get the "on-hold" parsed. You might also want to override the `ConverTo()` for printing the `EnumMember` value to swagger. It is a bit hacky, but if you want a pure .NET solution this should be one of the minimal viable solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation guide [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0), you can create your own versions of Microsoft's classes [`EnumTypeModelBinderProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/EnumTypeModelBinderProvider.cs), [`EnumTypeModelBinder`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/EnumTypeModelBinder.cs) (and base class [`SimpleTypeModelBinder`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs)) that replace incoming enum value names that have been renamed via `EnumMemberAttribute` with the original enum names before binding:

```
// Begin code for enum model binding
public class EnumMemberEnumTypeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider 
{
    public EnumMemberEnumTypeModelBinderProvider(MvcOptions options) { }

    public IModelBinder? GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        
        if (context.Metadata.IsEnum)
        {
            var enumType = context.Metadata.UnderlyingOrModelType;
            Debug.Assert(enumType.IsEnum);
            var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            if (EnumExtensions.TryGetEnumMemberOverridesToOriginals(enumType, out var overridesToOriginals))
                return new EnumMemberEnumTypeModelBinder(suppressBindingUndefinedValueToEnumType: true, enumType, loggerFactory, overridesToOriginals);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}

public class EnumMemberEnumTypeModelBinder : ExtensibleSimpleTypeModelBinder
{
    // Adapted from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/EnumTypeModelBinder.cs#L58
    readonly Type enumType;
    readonly bool isFlagged;
    readonly Dictionary<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, string> overridesToOriginals;
    readonly TypeConverter typeConverter;

    public EnumMemberEnumTypeModelBinder(bool suppressBindingUndefinedValueToEnumType, Type modelType, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, Dictionary<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, string> overridesToOriginals) : base(modelType, loggerFactory)
    {
        this.enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(modelType) ?? modelType;
        if (!this.enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.isFlagged = Attribute.IsDefined(enumType, typeof(FlagsAttribute));
        this.overridesToOriginals = overridesToOriginals ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(overridesToOriginals));
        this.typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.enumType);
    }
    
    protected override string? GetValueFromBindingContext(ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult) => 
        EnumExtensions.ReplaceRenamedEnumValuesToOriginals(base.GetValueFromBindingContext(valueProviderResult), isFlagged, overridesToOriginals);

    protected override void CheckModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, object? model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            base.CheckModel(bindingContext, valueProviderResult, model);
        }
        else if (IsDefinedInEnum(model, bindingContext))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                bindingContext.ModelName,
                bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueIsInvalidAccessor(
                    valueProviderResult.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private bool IsDefinedInEnum(object model, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Adapted from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/EnumTypeModelBinder.cs#L58
        var modelType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.UnderlyingOrModelType;

        // Check if the converted value is indeed defined on the enum as EnumTypeConverter
        // converts value to the backing type (ex: integer) and does not check if the value is defined on the enum.
        if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsFlagsEnum)
        {
            var underlying = Convert.ChangeType(
                model,
                Enum.GetUnderlyingType(modelType),
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
            var converted = model.ToString();
            return !string.Equals(underlying, converted, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        return Enum.IsDefined(modelType, model);
    }
}

public class ExtensibleSimpleTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    // Adapted from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs
    private readonly TypeConverter _typeConverter;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ExtensibleSimpleTypeModelBinder(Type type, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : this(type, loggerFactory, null) { }
    
    public ExtensibleSimpleTypeModelBinder(Type type, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, TypeConverter? typeConverter)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        if (loggerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        _typeConverter = typeConverter ?? TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ExtensibleSimpleTypeModelBinder>();
    }

    protected virtual string? GetValueFromBindingContext(ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult) => valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        //_logger.AttemptingToBindModel(bindingContext);

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            //_logger.FoundNoValueInRequest(bindingContext);
            // no entry
            //_logger.DoneAttemptingToBindModel(bindingContext);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

        try
        {
            var value = GetValueFromBindingContext(valueProviderResult);

            object? model;
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string))
            {
                // Already have a string. No further conversion required but handle ConvertEmptyStringToNull.
                if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    model = null;
                else
                    model = value;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                // Other than the StringConverter, converters Trim() the value then throw if the result is empty.
                model = null;
            }
            else
            {
                model = _typeConverter.ConvertFrom(context: null,culture: valueProviderResult.Culture, value: value);
            }

            CheckModel(bindingContext, valueProviderResult, model);

            //_logger.DoneAttemptingToBindModel(bindingContext);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var isFormatException = exception is FormatException;
            if (!isFormatException && exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                // TypeConverter throws System.Exception wrapping the FormatException,
                // so we capture the inner exception.
                exception = System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception.InnerException).SourceException;
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName,exception, bindingContext.ModelMetadata);

            // Were able to find a converter for the type but conversion failed.
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected virtual void CheckModel(
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult,
        object? model)
    {
        // When converting newModel a null value may indicate a failed conversion for an otherwise required
        // model (can't set a ValueType to null). This detects if a null model value is acceptable given the
        // current bindingContext. If not, an error is logged.
        if (model == null && !bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsReferenceOrNullableType)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                bindingContext.ModelName,
                bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
                    valueProviderResult.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
    }
}

// End code for enum model binding

/********************************************************/
// Begin general enum parsing code

public class CharMemoryComparer : IEqualityComparer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>
{
    public static CharMemoryComparer OrdinalIgnoreCase { get; } = new CharMemoryComparer(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    public static CharMemoryComparer Ordinal { get; }  = new CharMemoryComparer(StringComparison.Ordinal);

    readonly StringComparison comparison;
    CharMemoryComparer(StringComparison comparison) => this.comparison = comparison;
    public bool Equals(ReadOnlyMemory<char> x, ReadOnlyMemory<char> y) => MemoryExtensions.Equals(x.Span, y.Span, comparison);
    public int GetHashCode(ReadOnlyMemory<char> obj) => String.GetHashCode(obj.Span, comparison);
}

public static partial class EnumExtensions
{
    public const char FlagSeparatorChar = ',';
    public const string FlagSeparatorString = ", ";
    
    public static bool TryGetEnumMemberOverridesToOriginals(Type enumType, [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out Dictionary<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, string>? overridesToOriginals)
    {
        if (enumType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumType));
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(enumType));
        overridesToOriginals = null;
        foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
        {
            if (TryGetEnumAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(enumType, name, out var attr) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr.Value))
            {
                overridesToOriginals = overridesToOriginals ?? new(CharMemoryComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                overridesToOriginals.Add(attr.Value.AsMemory(), name);
            }
        }
        return overridesToOriginals != null;
    }
    
    public static bool TryGetEnumAttribute<TAttribute>(Type type, string name, [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out TAttribute? attribute) where TAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        var member = type.GetMember(name).SingleOrDefault();
        attribute = member?.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(false);
        return attribute != null;
    }
    
    public static string? ReplaceRenamedEnumValuesToOriginals(string? value, bool isFlagged, Dictionary<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, string> overridesToOriginals)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return value;
        var trimmed = value.AsMemory().Trim();
        if (overridesToOriginals.TryGetValue(trimmed, out var @override))
            value = @override;
        else if (isFlagged && trimmed.Length > 0)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            bool replaced = false;
            foreach (var n in trimmed.Split(EnumExtensions.FlagSeparatorChar, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries))
            {
                ReadOnlySpan<char> toAppend;
                if (overridesToOriginals.TryGetValue(n, out var @thisOverride))
                {
                    toAppend = thisOverride.AsSpan();
                    replaced = true;
                }
                else
                    toAppend = n.Span;
                sb.Append(sb.Length == 0 ? null : EnumExtensions.FlagSeparatorString).Append(toAppend);
            }
            if (replaced)
                value = sb.ToString();
        }
        return value;
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> Split(this ReadOnlyMemory<char> chars, char separator, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
    {
        int index;
        while ((index = chars.Span.IndexOf(separator)) >= 0)
        {
            var slice = chars.Slice(0, index);
            if ((options & StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) == StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
                slice = slice.Trim();
            if ((options & StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) == 0 || slice.Length > 0)
                yield return slice;
            chars = chars.Slice(index + 1);
        }
        if ((options & StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) == StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
            chars = chars.Trim();
        if ((options & StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) == 0 || chars.Length > 0)
            yield return chars;
    }
}
```

Then add the binder in `ConfigureServices()` like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
                            {
                                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new EnumMemberEnumTypeModelBinderProvider(options));
                            });
}
```

Notes:

- `EnumTypeModelBinder` and base class `SimpleTypeModelBinder` provide no useful extension points to customize the parsing of the incoming value string, thus it was necessary to copy some of their logic.
- Precisely emulating the logic of `SimpleTypeModelBinder` is somewhat difficult because it supports both numeric and textual enum values -- including mixtures of both for flags enums.  The binder above retains that capability, but at a cost of also allowing original enum names to be bound successfully.  Thus the values `on-hold` and `onhold` will be bound to `Status.OnHold`.
- Conversely, if you do not want to support binding of numeric values for enums, you could adapt the code of `JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061296/3744182) to *[System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59059989/3744182)*.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pa6pD). This approach also avoids binding to the original, unrenamed enum names.
- Matching of override names with original enum names is case-insensitive, so override names that differ only in case are not supported.