# ReadJson is not called for ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 project (not Core)

```
public ActionResult Magic()
{
    MyType model = BuildModel();
    return View("Index", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Magic(MyType model)
{
}

public class MyType
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<MySubType>))]
    public TySubType Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<MySubType>))]
public enum MySubType
{
    [EnumMember("v1")]
    MyV1
}

public class MyConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    where T: Enum
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType is T;
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {}

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {}
}
```

With this configuration, my `WriteJson` is called on GET, but not used on POST to deserialize the body. What should be changed here?

In the end, I'm trying to get it using the `EnumMember` value to serialize/deserialize enums

Comment: Json.NET's [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) already suppports `EnumMemberAttribute`, and has done so since [Json.NET 4.0 Release 2](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/04/21/json-net-4-0-release-2-nuget-1-2-and-dynamic).  If that is what you want, why are you creating your own converter?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the raw POST including the headers and body?  Is there a chance you are posting your values in the query string rather than the request body?

Comment: @dbc you're right, I use JSON encoder to pass it to the page, but the data is submitted as a Form url-encoded data and it does not go thru my logic. is that possible to deserialize form data with my converter?

Comment: A `JsonConverter` and Json.NET in general are only designed to deserialize JSON -- a *lightweight, text-based, language-independent data interchange format* defined by [rfc8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).  You can't use them to deserialize anything other than data in the support formats. (BSON is also supported).  For URL parameter binding you need a custom model binder or type converter.

Comment: See: [Deserialize enums using the EnumMember value in AspNet `[FromQuery]` model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72886747/3744182).  In fact that may be a duplicate despite being asked about .NET Core; agree?